# Fetching objects from database in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, doctrine, twig

I have entity Domain which has fields id, domain, users
in field users, I have an id which is the id of the user who created that domain.

now I have created **for** in the template which will display every domain that the user created.

I messed it up somehow and I don't know how to solve it.

**workspaces.html.twig**

```
{% for domain in workspaces %}
    <div class="workspace card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{workspaces.number}}</h4>
            <a href="/project" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**MainController.php**

```php
public function show()
{
    //todo: show domains for current user
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Domain::class);

    $currentUser = $this->getUser()->getID();
    $workspaces = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Domain::class)
        ->findByUsers($currentUser);
    return $this->render('workspaces.html.twig',array('workspaces' => $workspaces));
}
```

**DomainRepository.php**

```php
/**
 * @param $currentUser
 * @return Domain[] Returns an array of Domain objects
*/

public function findByUsers($currentUser)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->andWhere('d.users = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $currentUser)
        ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(15)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Error that I get: **Key "domain" for an array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.**
currently, I got 2 records in the database but when I add more then the error shows more keys "0, 1, 2..."

I know that I somehow messed up **for** or something (bad naming does not help :( ).

Comment: what is `{{workspaces.number}}` supposed to be? what type of relation do you have between Domain and User, OneToOne, ManyToMany?

Comment: should be `{{ domain.id }}` instead of `{{ workspaces.number }}`

Comment: @ArleighHix I forgot to change "number" for "domain". relation is ManyToMany.

Comment: @Rufinus then i get **Variable "workspaces" does not exist.**

Comment: if the code you showed is all you have, thant it can't be. workspaces is defined in your controller - the for loop is the only one accessing the collection array.

Comment: i know what is happening now.
i get array of objects
``` 
('workspaces.html.twig', array('workspaces' => array(object(Domain), object(Domain))))
```
how to get field domain from object Domain from every record in array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check your query if its working?
if its working there is a problem in your code

First let's clean a little the code.

**MainController.php**

```
    public function showAction()
    {
        //todo: show domains for current user

        $currentUser = $this->getUser()->getID();
        $workspaces = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Domain::class)
            ->getDomainsByUser($currentUser);

        return $this->render('workspaces.html.twig',array('workspaces' => $workspaces));
    }
```

**DomainRepository.php**

```
public function getDomainsByUser($currentUser)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->andWhere('d.users = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $currentUser)
        ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(15)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**workspaces.html.twig**

```
The problem in the code is in the twig part.
{{ domain.domain }} not {{ workspaces.number }}

{% for domain in workspaces %}
    <div class="workspace card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ domain.domain }}</h4>
            <a href="/project" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The naming seems a bit off since your `Domain Entity` seems to have a field called `domain`. So your solution would look like this:

```
{% for domain in workspaces %} //loop workspaces = every domain object
    <div class="workspace card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{domain.domain}}</h4> //access domain field in object domain
            <a href="/project" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You loop over all `domain objects` and access the field you want to use, called `domain`.